# Select table from column value MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, heidisql

we have a SQL table "ContactLot" in this table we have a column "contactTableName" and "creationDate", i'm tring to get all ContactLot after 2020-02-01 (here i can use creationDate column"  and then i want to get some values from every table in contactTableName column, can you help me ?
i'm using HeidiSQL (MySQL)

this is my request

`SELECT  COUNT(*)  FROM ContactLot.contactLotTableName 
WHERE ContactLot.creationDate > '2020-02-01 00:00:00'`

I know thise request is not correct but i put it just for exemple.

Thank you.

[image: exemple of ContactLot table and contatactTableName column]

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so please define what you mean by "after 2020-02-01".  Also provide a database tag.

Comment: for the DATE we have a column "creationDate" in ContactLot Table, so we can use WHERE clause to get all table after X date.

Comment: Could you provide which database engine you are using and put it in tags?

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: okey i did it, mysql with heidiSQL, thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

You table alias is wrong.  That seems to be about it.  I would suggest:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM ContactLot.contactLotTableName cl
WHERE cl.creationDate > '2020-02-01';
```

Note that "after 2020-02-01" is a bit misleading.  This will get anything on that date, but not at midnight when the day begins.  You probably want one of these conditions:

```
WHERE cl.creationDate >= '2020-02-01'

WHERE cl.creationDate >= '2020-02-02'
```

Comment: i had this response SELECT command denied to user **** but when i use the same request and i replace ContactLot.contactLotTableName with one of my tables i get the results...